# streaming data from a server

Tags: iphone

I would like to have all my data on a server be streamed into my iphone app.

How does this work?

e.g. images, text and sound

Should this be read into an array and then manipulated?

As I would like the app to be update-able whenever new content is added to the server.

This obviously means building the app in such a way that it wont crash or have errors due to updates.

How is this done? Is there single folder for each which is streamed in e.g. sound clips folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood from your question is that you want to play sounds, videos on your iphone app over the internet.

### **Images:**

To display image on your iphone over the internet is very easy all you have to do is publish your website somewhere then iphone will use the hyperlink of that image meaning like when you browse any image in your browser you get **e.g:**

http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png your iphone app will just call this URL to display the image.

### **For Sound And Videos**

They both will also be published on the website and they will have URL so that your iPhone App can access them to pause & stop the sound/video you just have to stop buffering & as a precaution you can save the location of buffer & if you want to Resume just start buffering from the saved buffer location

Comment: thank you. I was wondering if I want to keep the app updatable e.g. have a folder on the server full of images, then the app reads in the folder and fills an array for example with all the images which I can then use in the app. So that I can just update the server and not the app. How does one parse in the folder or images/sounds?

Comment: you do have to keep an folder on server so that you can store them and you have to make your app update-able but when you update it its upto you if you want to update it after specific time period then you have to make your app threaded so that your app can work properly even when you are doing a server call. And for your second question first tell me what server language will you use?

Comment: I am not sure. I have never streamed from a server into an iphone app. I need to research a little.

Comment: I meant will you use ASP.NET or PHP because of you use ASP.NET(C#) then it has alot of built-in functions to traverse folders to get files list.

Comment: Thanks. I will find that out. how does the data get read in? What format? I am trying to make sense of this all :)

Comment: It'll be NSDATA. E.g: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/create-a-basic-iphone-audio-player-with-av-foundation-framework